# Bridged Adapter Issue Windows 10 VB 5.0.12 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm learning Node.js and I've installed VirtualBox and there ubuntu server 14.04. Node.js is installed as well on ubuntu. I'm doing an exercise in which I created a server which is accessible from guest_localhost:3000 (in ubuntu). The thing is I've not installed any GUI (and I wish to continue in that way). I want to test that the server I created using Node.js is running. To do that I just need to go to server_localhost:3000. 
Apparently everything is ok (for example ping host to guest ip), but for some reason it´s not working.

[ping ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU98b.png) __  [not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBpPF.png)

```
`var http = require('http');

var handleRequest = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Welcome to Node Essential Training\n');
};

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(3000, 'localhost');`
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any GUI to visibly verify your page layout, you should be able to access it from your windows machine if they are in the same local network by simply accessing the url http://your_ubuntu_local_ip:3000 where your_ubuntu_local_ip is the local ip your ubuntu machine has internally in your local network. You can find this ip by typing `ifconfig` in your ubuntu terminal and looking for the ip the network adapter you are using has.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I've found is that I have to configure Bridge Networking in VirtualBox. I have the latest version. The manual https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged is not up to date apparently. Anyway I followed what it says so I chose "Bridge Adapter" (instead of Bridge Network) and cannot find the host interface to select they say. Then I try to access to my ubuntu_localhost:3000 but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Follow the instructions in [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/how-can-i-access-apache-on-virtualbox-guest-from-host) and you should be able to access your guest machine from your host machine.

Comment: I've done everything possible. I think guest and host machines are now in the same ip range but still doesn't work. Thanks for the link but what I'm looking for is a bit different. What I want is set up "Bridged Adapter" in order to access to ubuntu local ip. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. The problem was in the code to create the server after all. As I'm learning JavaScript and Node.js I'm watching a tutorial in Lynda.com. The code which doesn't work comes from Lynda. The other from this url: http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs

```
// THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK
//var http = require('http');
//
//var handleRequest = function (req, res) {
//  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
//  res.end('Welcome to Node Essential Training\n');
//};
//
//var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
//
//server.listen(8080, 'localhost');

//THIS CODE WORKS
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=3000; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```